# passing python subprocess arguments through a list on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess

Working on my python skills.trying to pass arguments for subprocess.run through a list. It works fine when all the arguments are available but it doesn't take a list.

Is this supported when i want to pass all the arguments in this fashion?

```
import sys
import os
import re
import shutil
import subprocess

com_files=["compress","/c"]

if '--tozip' in sys.argv[1]:
    for dir in sys.argv[2:]:
        for i_dir in os.listdir(dir):
            if re.search(r'__\w',i_dir):
                com_files.append(os.path.abspath(dir)+'\\'+i_dir)
    print(com_files)
    subprocess.run(com_files)
```

Here is the error message:

```
['compress', '/c', 'C:\\temp\\google\\xyz__hello__.txt', 'C:\\temp\\google\\zz__something__.jpg']
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\copyspecial.py", line 45, in main
subprocess.call(com_files)
 File "C:\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
 File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in init
restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specifi
```

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an error message?

Comment: ['compress', '/c', 'C:\\temp\\google\\xyz__hello__.txt', 'C:\\temp\\google\\zz__something__.jpg']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\copyspecial.py", line 45, in main
    subprocess.call(com_files)
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specifi

Comment: Have both the files in that location

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Please include the error with its original formatting -- across multiple lines, with whitespace, &c. I've tried to reconstruct, but that reconstruction is doubtless imperfect.

Comment: Also, this is actually behavior that's different between Windows and UNIX -- it might be worth tagging/titling with your platform. The passing-a-list form is correct on UNIX, but Windows is a different animal.

Comment: (UNIX passes an array of strings into a new program when it's started, so the list is actually the native data structure, and using a string instead is creating an extra layer of indirection with room for bugs &c. as fallout; Windows passes a string, which the program being invoked is expected to parse).

Comment: This is because `compress` is not in your windows path. Can you type `compress` from a windows cmd prompt?

Comment: Your code is correct (AFAICT) which means your *environment* is broken...

Comment: This is a default process available in Windows. When arguments processed directly it works fine.